# require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php

> Warning: require_once(C:/wamp/www/saleshub/system/startup.php): failed
> to open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\saleshub\index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/saleshub/system/startup.php'
> (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\saleshub\index.php on line 17

index.php

```
<?php
// Version
define('VERSION', '2.0.2.0');

// Configuration
if (is_file('config.php')) {
    require_once('config.php');
}

// Install
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
    header('Location: install/index.php');
    exit;
}

// Startup
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');

// Registry
$registry = new Registry();

// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);


startup.php coding 

<?php
// Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Check Version
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.3.0', '<') == true) {
    exit('PHP5.3+ Required');
}

if (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
}

// Windows IIS Compatibility
if (!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) {
    if (isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
        $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace('\\', '/', substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, 0 - strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in your `DIR_SYSTEM`constant?

Answer (score 0):

I think your variable is wrong. I am just assuming from your if condition. You need `DIR_APPLICATION` not `DIR_SYSTEM`. So your code will be :

```
require_once(DIR_APPLICATION. 'startup.php');
```